# Python - Terminate a program from tkinter button click?

Tags: python, tkinter, while-loop

### I am trying to terminate a simple while loop from a tkinter window button but i am unable to do so here:

Recorder.py

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
import numpy as np
import cv2
import ctypes
user32 = ctypes.windll.user32
screensize = user32.GetSystemMetrics(0), user32.GetSystemMetrics(1)

def record_screen():

    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
    out = cv2.VideoWriter('ResultFile.avi', fourcc, 25.0, screensize)

    while True:
        try:
            img = ImageGrab.grab()
            img_np = np.array(img)
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(img_np, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            out.write(frame)
            print('recording....')
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            break

    out.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# uncomment when running as main
#record_screen()
```

*and here's the tkinter code*

```
from tkinter import *
import Recorder

class Trial:

    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        # self.printButton = Button(frame, text="Print Message", command=self.printMessage)
        # self.printButton.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.recorderButton = Button(frame, text="Start Recording", command=Recorder.record_screen)
        self.recorderButton.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.quitButton = Button(frame, text="Quit Recording", command=root.destroy)
        self.quitButton.pack(side=LEFT)

    # same freezing problem with method approach
    # def quitFunction(self):
    #     root.destroy()

    # def printMessage(self):
    #    print("Hello .....")

root = Tk()
alpha = Trial(root)
root.mainloop()
```

*The problem is that when i simply click the Quit button the tk code does as expected , however the very minute the recording starts it creates an infinite loop that i believe is preventing the Quit button to terminate the window*

Comment: You probably will need to change the logic of quitting the application

Comment: Put your recorder in a new thread and use a flag for your while loop instead of `True`.

Comment: can you be more specific

Comment: its just that i have never worked with threads i tried the following:

Comment: 'class Recording(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        from PIL import ImageGrab
        import numpy as np'